# WPF UserControl using MVVMLight can't find ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I've got two problems.  I have a WPF UserControl that is a .dll plugin to another WPF application.

The first is, unless I install MVVMLight in the WPF application that is using my Usercontrol dll, it complains it can't find any MVVMLight libraries.  Is there anyway I don't have to install MVVMLight on the Main WPF application using my UserControl dll?

Second is, it can't find the ViewModelLocator in my UserControl.  I've tried making it a StaticResource of my UserControl but it can't find the ViewModelLocator.

Please help.

Comment: Obviously your UserControl has a dependency upon MvvmLight. You will either have to remove this dependency or make sure that you always bring in the MvvmLight assemblies into any application that uses your UserControl.

Comment: So there is no way to bundle them in my DLL?  Also, any ideas as to why it can't find my ViewModelLocator?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use a View Model Locator:

**Start with a simple `ViewModel`:**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; } = "ViewModelLocator works fine!";
}
```

**Define the `ViewModelLocator`:**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private static readonly MainViewModel mainViewModel;

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    }

    public static MainViewModel MainViewModel => mainViewModel;
}
```

As you see, your ViewModel's instance is created only once in the static constructor, and after that, the same instance is returned.

**And here is the `View`:**

```
<Window x:Class="SetViewModelLocator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SetViewModelLocator"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SetViewModelLocator.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=MainViewModel}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestProperty}"/>
</Grid>
```

Set the Locator as a `Resource` and use it as the `DataContext` of your main container which in this case is a `Grid`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  I need it to be in a UserControl in a DLL and then use it in another WPF project that I can't modify the app.xaml to put the Locator in.  My problem is my Locator can't be found inside the UserControl.